# I made a chat app, It worked all fine while connected to debug mode, but when i install through release apk on device, it crash

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, crash, apk

[I get this error message on clicking on send bug report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLRgS.jpg)

I have tried everything in my reach.

Please help me if anyone knows how to fix this, for this sole purpose only, i joined this community today. I am new to Flutter and Android and it took me around 2 weeks, i was so excited about this  when running in debugging mode until i found it crashes on release apk

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: The problem, it dont shows any error in debugging mode but when installing through release apk, it get crashes

Comment: You would have missed to add your release SHA in firebase and add that json in your project. Also remember to add internet permission in android manifest

Comment: You need to Add SHA-1 fingerprint to firebase console for particular package or bundle id that is release SHA-1 fingerprint. Android Manifest which is inside main folder of android folder needed permission of internet as well and if you are targetting android 12 device then you have to write attribute "android:exported" = true to Activity declared inside manifest.